# Issues with JavaScript Form Validation

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do Form validation to validate the information request form by checking that the following fields in the form have been filled out:

▪ Name field
▪ Email field
▪ Comments

My function validateName() does not work at all it causes the other functions not to work either (adding default values to fields and removal of defaults when text area is clicked). When I remove the validateName() the functions I previously created work fine.  It should be noted that I have addded the onsubmit="return validateName()" to the form element. I will also need to create a validateEmail() and validateComments() respectively.

I would also like the function for validateName(), validateEmail(), and validateComments() validation to check the following:

▪ Check if the form field is empty when submitted 
▪ Check if the default text is in the form field when submitted

I have commented out the 2 validateName() functions I attempted to use so my other functions will work.

```
    function formtext(){
        document.contact.Name.value="Enter your name.";
        document.contact.Email.value="Enter your email address.";
        document.contact.questions.value="Enter your comments.";
    }
    function delete_email(){
        document.contact.Email.value = "";
    }
    function delete_name(){
        document.contact.Name.value = "";
    }
    function delete_comments(){
        document.contact.questions.value = "";
    }

   /* function validateName()
    {
        var x=document.contact.Name.value;
        if (x==null || x=="")

        {
            alert("Name must be filled out");
            return false;
        }
    }  */

    /* function validateName()
    {
        var x=document.contact.["Name"].value;
        if (x==null || x=="")
        {
            alert("Name must be filled out");
            return false;
        }
    }    */

</script>
```

Comment: What about **jQuery**, why not use it?

Comment: Try giving an `id` attribute to each of the fields and use `if(document.getElementById('nameField').value == '')`
I'll try creating a fiddle and post the link here

Comment: @user2422696 : If you get stuck somewhere , post it, we'll be glad to help.Good Luck :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
var defaultName == 'Please Enter Name', defaultEmail == 'Please Enter Email', defaultComment == 'Please Enter Comment';
function validateForm()
    {
        if(document.getElementById('namefield').value == '' || (document.getElementById('namefield').value == defaultName)
        {
            alert('Please enter name'); 
        }
        if(document.getElementById('emailfield').value == '' || (document.getElementById('emailfield').value == defaultEmail)
        {
            alert('Please enter email');    
        }
        if(document.getElementById('commentsfield').value == '' || (document.getElementById('commentsfield').value == defaultComment)
        {
            alert('Please enter comments'); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am sorry.Copy pasting from dreamweaver is removing all formatting

Comment: I am thinking for the requirement "Check if the default text is in the form field when submitted" I could add an or condition to lets after value == but how can I make reference to the to the text? It exists within my function below so I thinking I will need to create a variable. Any ideas? function formtext(){ document.contact.Name.value="Enter your name."; document.contact.Email.value="Enter your email address."; document.contact.questions.value="Enter your comments."; }

Comment: @aplata : Define variables in JavaScript initially as `var defaultName = 'Enter your name here'` . Then , you can perform a check like 
`if(document.getElementById('nameField').value == '' ||  document.getElementById('nameField').value == defaultName)`

Comment: Sorry harsha what you provided worked. I am just trying to figure out how I can check if the default text is in the form field when submitted which was my last comment. Thanks

Comment: @aplata : Please take a look at the edited answer,it takes care of the default name in the form field check.Also, if my answer helped you , please consider accepting it as the answer,

Comment: Harsha you are absolutely awesome and thanks for your help. It worked like a charm I guess I thought there would be a conflict with the formtext() function but there wasn't any.

Comment: @aplata : Glad I could be of help :)

Comment: @harsha, line per line you could use the backticks, but when you wish to format a paragraph an indentation of 4 spaces is more effective (or use the "format code" button)